# Why the warning not to use Raspbian Stretch for the Serverless Pi cluster?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

In examining this article,

[Your Serverless Raspberry Pi cluster](https://blog.alexellis.io/your-serverless-raspberry-pi-cluster/)

[image]

It very specifically states

> Note: do not download Raspbian Stretch
>
> The community is helping the Docker team to ready support for Raspbian Stretch, but it's not yet seamless. Please download Jessie from the RPi foundation's archive.

The question is in the title:  Why the warning not to use Stretch?

What is it about Stretch that is not compatible with Jessie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the docker support for Debian 9 on Raspberry isn't "production ready". So the article advise against using Stretch.

Reference:

Debian 9 = Stretch

Docker = Containers, kind of a virtualization, but not really.

Explaining Docker: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)

Comment: Docker does count as OS level virtualization, much like openVZ.